# Back link to previous app from containing app progmatically in case of deeplinks

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, ios-extensions, ios-keyboard-extension

I created a keyboard extension with a scan button to open a barcode scanner in my containing app. When the scan is completed, it should navigate back to the initial app and the barcode data should be set as text to the textfield that initiated the keyboard and we clicked on scan button.

[image]

There is this app Scandit Wedge that does it the same way. But I couldn't find a way to achieve the same.
Please refer GIF below.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/id123-dev-ios/scandit.gif

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing at the moment exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: @mh-itc Using private APIs for doing this for now.

Comment: @SameerBhide Which type of private API did you use for this? Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @SameerBhide can you please answer your question? Which private APIs did you use? The accepted answer is not working for me :/

Comment: @ndreisg I implemented the above using Google custom keyboard like implementation. See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42516357/how-does-googles-custom-ios-keyboard-gboard-programmatically-dismiss-the-fron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to switch to the previous app, here is the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13447282/1433612

But you could do that if you know the app's bundle id and url scheme. You can find unofficial lists on internet. Assuming that you are able to recognize the source app you can do something like this in your `AppDelegate`:

```
public func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    guard let applicationBundleId = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String else {
        return true
    }

    // Save your source application
    sourceApplicationBundleId = applicationBundleId
    return true
}

var sourceApplicationBundleId: String?

// Attempt to open application from which your app was opened
func openApplication() {
    guard let applicationBundleId = sourceApplicationBundleId, let url = url(for: applicationBundleId) else {
        return
    }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}

func url(for bundleId: String) -> URL? {
    guard let scheme = knownUrlSchemes[bundleId] else {
        return nil
    }

    return URL(string: scheme)!
}

// A list of known url schemes
var knownUrlSchemes: Dictionary<String, String> = {
    return ["com.google.Maps": "comgooglemaps://",
            "com.facebook.Facebook": "fb://"]
}()
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer is accepted. The question was about a keyboard extension calling the containing app. So the `sourceApplicationBundleId` will always be the bundle id of the keyboard extension and it can not be opened via URLScheme.